# Insert two arrays into one mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I have two arrays:

```
name - facebook,google,yahoo
url - facebook.com,google.com,yahoo.com
```

In my database, I have a table (tbl_websites).
structure : id, site_name, site_url

I want to insert the data from those two arrays into a single row in that table.

example:
(row 1)

```
id : 1
site_name : facebook
site_url : facebook.com
```

(row 2)

```
id : 2
site_name : google
site_url : google.com
```

(row 3)

```
id : 3
site_name : yahoo
site_url : yahoo.com
```

How do I do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: that's the opposite of one row...that's 3 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is a direct 1:1 match between the arrays, you can simply loop over one of them as in:

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
  $name_value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
  $url_value = mysql_real_escape_string($url[$key]);

  // Addendum: If there was a third array, just use `$key` as the array key
  // same as done with $url[$key]
  $thrid_value = mysql_real_escape_string($third_arr[$key]);

  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_websites (site_name, site_url, third_value) VALUES ('$name_value', '$url_value', '$third_value')");
}
```

This assumes the `id` is an auto-increment value.  I have, for simplicity brevity, used the `mysql_query()` function here.  But it is recommended to use a prepared statement via an api like PDO instead.  The process of retrieving them from the arrays is the same.

#### PDO version (assumes connection already made in `$db`):

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {   
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_websites (site_name, site_url) VALUES (:name, :url)");
  $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name_value, ':url' => $url_value));
}
```

The code above doesn't include any error checking.  Read the [PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) for examples on error checking with a PDO statement. It can be done either with a `try/catch` exception block or with PHP warnings.

Comment: how about if it came from three different arrays? what adjustments do i have to make?

Comment: @ Michael how about if it came from three different arrays? what adjustments do i have to make ?

Comment: @mackynyxzz I added a little more above. If there's a third array, just use `$third_array[$key]` Using `$key` as the array key is the important part.

Comment: thanks a lot man. this really works. I really appreciate yor help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it one query (better performance):

```
$values = array_map(function($name, $url){
    return "('$name', '$url')";
}, array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $name), array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $url));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_websites` (`site_name`, `site_url`) VALUES " . implode(' ', $values));
```

Comment: Sorry had named the second array wrong. It should be fine now.